# One Java Swing PopupMenu for different JLists vs One Menu per JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist, popupmenu

I created a popup Menu with 2 menu items : Edit and Remove. And then, I added this menu to 2 different JLists.

The result of clicking Edit or Remove is different between JLists, because they refer to different objects (Remove Menu Item: One should remove one object from an array and the other should remove a different object from a different array).

I'm wondering which is the best way to do it, performance or "good-coding" wise. Create a different popup menu for each component or use the same popup menu?

I am using the following code to find out which JList it is:

```
JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu("Menu");
addPopup(listShowSources, popupMenu);
addPopup(listShowESS, popupMenu);


JMenuItem menuItemEdit = new JMenuItem("Edit");
popupMenu.add(menuItemEdit);

JMenuItem menuItemRemove = new JMenuItem("Remove");
popupMenu.add(menuItemRemove);
menuItemRemove.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        Component c = (Component)arg0.getSource();
        JPopupMenu popup = (JPopupMenu)c.getParent();
        JList<String> list = (JList <String> )popup.getInvoker();
        System.out.println(list.getName());
    }
});
```

With this code, I'll be creating instances of Popup menus and lists every time I press the button. Is this the "best" way to do this or should I just make 2 different popup menus?

Thank you for the help,
Nhekas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One should remove one object from an array and the other should remove a different object from a different array).

You should not be using Arrays.

Swing uses a modified Model-View-Controller (MVC) design. Basically this means that the data display in the `JList` must be contained in the `ListModel`. So if you want to change the `JList` you change the `ListModel`.

So there is no need for the array (i.e. you don't want to keep the data in two places). The `DefaultListModel` has methods that allow you to update the model directly.

So your basic code is correct in that you get the invoker of the popup. So now all you need to do is get the `DefaultListModel`:

```
DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)list.getModel();
model.remove(...);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I am using the list models. However, I do need the data on a Array due to other operations of my code. I use these Jlists mostly to display how many objects I have in each array so the user can select which one it needs for other operations.
This said, I use the list model to remove and insert items into these JLists, just like you said.
However, in your opinion, should I do it like I shown in the code in the question, or should I create 2 different popup menus at the start? Thanks!

Comment: `I do need the data on a Array due to other operations of my code` - when you need data from the model then you use the `elementAt(...)` method from the DefaultListModel.  So when the user selects an item for processing, that is the time you get the data from the `ListModel`. Don't try to keep a separate Array, you can easily iterate through all the Items in the ListModel or access one item at a time. The different is you use a method with a parameter instead of using an array with an index. If you design the application properly there is no need for two menus.

Comment: ok! thanks a lot for your answer and thorough explanation! It was very helpfull and answered my question!